# Interaction among turtles based on their internal variables in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo, suppose there are two kinds (breeds) of turtles: AAA and BBB.

```
breed [ AAA ]
breed [ BBB ]
AAA-own [ vvv ]
BBB-own [ vvv ]
```

Suppose I am iterating over AAA, and when an AAA finds a BBB nearby, it steals 10% of `vvv` from the BBB individual. If there is a global variable called `dummy`, the following code may work:

```
to function-name
  let QQQ one-of BBB in-radius 1
  ask QQQ [
    set dummy vvv * 0.1
    set vvv vvv - dummy
  ]
  set vvv vvv + dummy
end
```

Is there any way to do the similar thing without using the global variable, `dummy`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [myself](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself) for the turtle who asked.